# filtered.length does not work with grouping items | angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have 2 problems with my code:

1) decisive code of my simple code below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in filtered = (cars | filter:search)">
{{filtered.length}}
```

But it doesnt work. Why?

2) When I choose radio "**ALL**", then name of  group is "**undefined**". How can I rename it to "**all cars**" ?

my code is on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aF2aL/24/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question first, you would want to create a function to handle the case of "ALL" since its returned value would be "undefined", so it would look like:

```
<th colspan="4">{{ showGroup(group) }}</th>
```

Then inside angular code:

```
 $scope.showGroup = function(group) {
    if( group == 'undefined' )
        return "All";
    else
        return group;
 };
```

And the reason why the filter array's length in the above HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in filtered = (cars | filter:search)">
{{filtered.length}}
```

is not showing is that the {{filtered.length}} is not wrapped in  tags. So, put the line  {{filtered.length}} into one of the  blocks underneath to see it in action:

```
<td>{{ $index + 1 }} {{filtered.length}}</td>
```

, or as I did in the JSfiddle below, added to the header for a better display:

```
<th colspan="4">{{ showGroup(group) }} Count: {{filtered.length}}</th>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aF2aL/25/

Comment: nice and clean solution. Thanks a lot!